# How do I use a gem from a pull request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to try out the changes which were made in this pull request:

https://github.com/neovintage/zoho_invoice/pull/10

How can I specify this in my Gemfile to use it?  Or is there a way to make a fork of that tree (pull request) so I can reference that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gem 'zoho_invoice', github: 'qualaroo/zoho_invoice'
```

There is a way to specify the exact commit as well, but I forget what it is exactly.

Comment: Indeed, this works, so the trick is to find the exact URL which is the owner name with the repository name behind it.  Thanks.